# Автообновление страницы при масшатибровании

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Вопрос следующий, как при масштабировании страницы включить автообновление страницы. Короч, когда я масштабирую свою страницу, у меня один сверху фиксированный блок масштабируется, но не так как второй блок, т.е. съезжает, а когда обновляешь страницу становится нужной ширины. мне нужно чтобы при масштабировании обновлялась страничка. Заранее спасибо

Comment: давай код на jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e){
 //здесь действия при масштабировании 
})
```